# Sending Table Type To Stored Procedure From Python

Tags: python, plsql, cx-oracle

I am sending Table Type to a stored procedure. Below are the declared types.

```
CREATE TYPE two_attr_ot AS OBJECT (
ssn      NUMBER,
fname    VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE TYPE two_attr_tt IS TABLE OF two_attr_ot;
```

Procedure

```
PROCEDURE set_emp_details(
    IN_save_data IN two_attr_tt
)
```

I am calling this procedure from python using cx_Oracle. conn is Connection Object.

```
tab = conn.gettype('two_attr_tt')
obj = conn.gettype('TWO_ATTR_OT')
new_obj = obj.newobject()
new_obj.SSN = 1111
new_obj.FNAME = 'John'
tab.append(new_obj)
conn.cursor().callproc('procname', [tab])
```

This is executing perfectly fine. But I want to set the attributes to new_obj dynamically using dynamic keys. Something like new_obj[key] = val.

How I can accomplish this.

Comment: Seems like new_obj.__setattr__(key,value) is working. Any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setattr(object, name, value).

```
setattr(new_obj, 'SSN', 1111)
setattr(new_obj, 'FNAME', 'John')
```